# Is there a cleaner way to write null propagation in the earlier version of C#?

Tags: c#

I have this class.

```
class Property
{
    public int? PropertyId { get; set; }
}
```

I have following statement that I wrote in C# 6.0

```
Property p = null;
var id = p?.PropertyId.GetValueOrDefault() ?? 0;
```

Turns out null propagation doesn't work in C# 5.0.  I rewrote it as:

```
int id = 0;
if (propertyByAddress != null && propertyByAddress.PropertyId != null)
{
    id = p.PropertyId.Value;
}
```

It seems unnecessarily wordy.  Is there a cleaner way to do it in C# 5.0?

Comment: That's about it as far as I know; ?. was probably my favorite feature of C# 6 :)

Comment: Why are you using `GetValueOrDefault`?  `p?.PropertyId ?? 0` should work the same.

Comment: I'd suggest an extension method, but that's likely even wordier (if that's a word)

Comment: @juharr Good point.  But moot in C# 5 :(

Comment: "It seems unnecessarily wordy." Well yes - otherwise the `?.` operator wouldn't have been introduced in C# 6. You can't have the benefits of C# 6's brevity in C# 5...

Comment: Doesn't this work in c# 5.0? - `p.PropertyId.Value == null ? 0 : p.PropertyId.Value`

Comment: @Unknown If `p` is null that throws an NRE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use [GetValueOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx) in C# 5.0, but yes your null check is necessary.

```
int id = 0;
Property p = null;

if (p != null)
    id = p.PropertyId.GetValueOrDefault();
```

You could also make an extension method as pointed out by Camilo, if you feel that's "cleaner".

**PropertyExtensions.cs**

```
public static int GetPropertyIdValueOrDefault(this Property p)
{
    if (p != null)
        return p.PropertyId.GetValueOrDefault();

    return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
Property p = null;
var id = p.GetPropertyIdValueOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ and a Maybe monad.  This will allow you to write e.g.

```
var supSupNameOpt =
  from employee in employeeOpt
  from supervisor in employee.ReportsTo
  from supervisorSupervisor in supervisor.ReportsTo
  select supervisorSupervisor.Name;
```

This would be equivalent to

```
var supSupNameOpt = employeeOpt?.ReportsTo?.ReportsTo?.Name;
```

So not as concise as `?.`, but much prettier than the [pyramid of doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)).

Here are some writeups: https://codewithstyle.info/understand-monads-linq/  https://ericlippert.com/2013/04/02/monads-part-twelve/

And note while most tutorials present a special `Maybe<T>` wrapper class for this, you can do it with plain old nulls to; see my comment at the bottom: https://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2008/12/11/the-maybe-monad-in-c/

Comment: Are you sure you answered the correct question? This has absolutely nothing to do with the question

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Do you know what a `Maybe` monad is?  It's a standard way of doing null propagation in functional languages.  How does that have nothing to do with the question?

Comment: I wonder who talked about functional languages... This is a simple POCO without any LINQ in the middle. Also, if anything, this far more wordier than a double if check

Comment: I agree that this approach is overkill. I do not agree that this approach is off topic, or irrelevant to non-functional languages.

Comment: Doesn't the null propogation go before the period? `?.` not `.?`

Answer (score 1):

Not as pretty as `?.`, but this would work:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static Tout N<Tin, Tout>(this Tin val, Func<Tin, Tout> e)
    {
        if (val == null)
            return default(Tout);

        return e(val);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var id = Property.N(p => p.PropertyId) ?? 0;
```